# PHP to show posts from category

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, tabs

I'm trying to code this slider for our Wordpress site to show in each box, the first, second and third most recent posts from the category (in this instance it's sports). No matter what I do with the count variable I can't get the other posts to show up, just the first one. Here is the loop I'm using and the code, the page is [smeharbinger.net/category/sports](http://smeharbinger.net/category/sports)

```
<div class="tabbed">

<!-- tab 1 -->
<div class="t1">
<ul>
    <?php
$count = 1; 
$tabbedSportsQuery = new WP_Query('cat='.get_query_var('cat').'&showposts=1');
while ($tabbedSportsQuery->have_posts()) : $tabbedSportsQuery->the_post(); 
echo '<div class="t'.$count.'">';
echo the_post_thumbnail(array(665,500), array ('class' => 'alignnone'));
$count++; 
endwhile;

?>

</ul>
</div>

<!-- tab 2 -->
<div class="t2">
<ul>
    <?php
  $count = 2; 
$tabbedSportsQuery = new WP_Query('cat='.get_query_var('cat').'&showposts=1');
while ($tabbedSportsQuery->have_posts()) : $tabbedSportsQuery->the_post(); 
echo '<div class="t'.$count.'">';
echo the_post_thumbnail(array(665,500), array ('class' => 'alignnone'));
$count = 2; 
endwhile;

?>

</ul>
</div>

<!-- tab 3 -->
<div class="t3">
<ul>
    <?php
$count = 3; 
$tabbedSportsQuery = new WP_Query('cat='.get_query_var('cat').'&showposts=1');
while ($tabbedSportsQuery->have_posts()) : $tabbedSportsQuery->the_post(); 
echo '<div class="t'.$count.'">';
echo the_post_thumbnail(array(665,500), array ('class' => 'alignnone'));
$count++; 
endwhile;

?>

</ul>
</div>

<!-- The tabs -->
<ul class="tabs">
<li class="t1"><a class="t1 tab" ><h10><?php echo get_the_title($ID); ?></h10></a>        </li>
<li class="t2"><a class="t2 tab" ><h10><?php echo get_the_title($ID); ?></h10></a>  </li>
<li class="t3"><a class="t3 tab" ><h10><?php echo get_the_title($ID); ?></h10></a>  </li>
</ul>

</div><!-- tabbed -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  Note:

- You only need to query once, but set the number of posts to 3.  A `while` loop will then loop through these for you.
- The `$count++` increases the count from 1 to 2 to 3.

  ```
  <?php
  $count = 1;
  $tabbedSportsQuery = new WP_Query(array(
      'cat' => get_query_var('cat'),
      'posts_per_page' => 3
  ));

  while ($tabbedSportsQuery->have_posts()) : $tabbedSportsQuery->the_post();
  ?>
      <div class="t<?php echo $count?>">
          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(665,500), array ('class' => 'alignnone')); ?></a>
      </div>
  <?php
  $count++;
  endwhile;
  ?>

  <!-- The tabs -->
  <ul class="tabs">
  <li class="t1"><a class="t1 tab" ><h10><?php echo get_the_title($ID); ?></h10></a>        </li>
  <li class="t2"><a class="t2 tab" ><h10><?php echo get_the_title($ID); ?></h10></a>  </li>
  <li class="t3"><a class="t3 tab" ><h10><?php echo get_the_title($ID); ?></h10></a>  </li>
  </ul>
  ```

Comment: Does the_post_thumbnail automatically wrap the image in an anchor tag?  Not sure... You might be able to remove that.

Comment: That works for pulling up the 3 most recent but it just shows them outside of tabs, what part of that do I want to use to put featured image 1 in tab 1, featured image 2 in tab 2, and etc.

Answer (score 0):

Hope below code will help you.. Loop thru the post and then print div for tab and then try to get remaining tabs into a variable and at end of while loop print that variable.

```
<?php
    $count = 1;
    $tabbedSportsQuery = new WP_Query(array(
        'cat' => get_query_var('cat'),
        'posts_per_page' => 3
    ));
    $out = '';
    while ($tabbedSportsQuery->have_posts()) : $tabbedSportsQuery->the_post();
?>
    <div class="t<?php echo $count?>">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(665,500), array ('class' => 'alignnone')); ?></a>
    </div>
    <?php 
        if($count == 1) {   
             $out .= '<ul class="tabs"><li class="t'.$count.'">';
            } else {
                $out .= '<li class="t'.$count.'">';
            }   
            $out .= '<a class="t'.$count.' tab"><h10>'.get_the_title($ID).'</h10></a>'; 
            if($count == 3) {   
                $out .= '</li></ul>';
            } else {
                $out .= '</li>';
        } 
    ?>
<?php
    $count++;
    endwhile;
    print $out;
?>
```